# how to add dynamic field to ui-grid header-name field

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

Grid which has one field name Users and requirement is it should display Users(count of Users) in `ui-grid` header-name. How can I get that.

This is my JS file code:

```
  var userCount= response.usercount;

      columnDefs: [{
                    name: 'Users', // Along with Users i want count also
                    width: '25%',                        
                    cellTemplate: 'beacon-template'
                },
```

How can I get that?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example?

Comment: I have ui-grid which have columns with header-name as Users, Firstname,Latname, Address. In Users Column in header i need Users(count of users) count of users in header name along with Users. I have this count value which is dynamic. How can i display along with header-name Users

Comment: I added one image to it it will help you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the header text. Sounds like you can put a watch to the count value and do something similar like the following:

```
$scope.$watch('yourCountValue', function(newVal){

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].displayName = 'Users(' + newVal + ')';

  $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
})
```

the code may vary in your case. For example, you may watch the $scope.data change instead and use $scope.data.length to concat the displayName. You may have select header and index will be 1 instead of 0, etc.

Updated Answer: did you forget to inject ui.grid and uiGridConstants?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants) {

  $scope.gridOptions = {

    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'field1', displayName: 'User 1'},
        {field: 'field2', displayName: 'User 2'},
    ],

    data: [
      { field1: "user 1", field2: "bar"},
      { field1: "user 2", field2: "bar"},
      { field1: "user 3", field2: "bar"}
    ],

    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
    };
    //put the watch here
    /...
}]);
```

Comment: can you show me more your code? Sounds like either you didn't inject the ui-grid module or didn't register the gridApi